# “Himmlische dein Heiligtum” – shouldn’t it be “himmlisches”?

Tags: adjective, adjective-ending, poetry

The famous poem goes like this:

> Wir betreten feuertrunken,
>   Himmlische, dein Heiligtum.

As I understand, these lines, in normal word order, should be like this:

> Feuertrunken, wir betreten dein himmlisches Heiligtum.

Is my syntactic analysis wrong? If not, why is the *-e* ending used instead of *-es*? This is even more interesting considering that using *-es* wouldn’t ruin the meter. Any insights?

Comment: If you place the adverb "Feuertrunken" into first position, you'll have to make sure the finite verb remains in second position: "Feuertrunken betreten wir..." This is where the meter is lost.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your syntactic analysis is wrong.

Joy, die Freude, is personalized in this poem, and is addressed here with the adjective himmlisch.

Compare:

> Armen Tsirunyan, I understand your question.
>
> I understand, Armen Tsirunyan, your question.
>
> Himmlische Freude, wir betreten feuertrunken Dein Heiligtum.
>
> Wir betreten feuertrunken, himmlische Freude, Dein Heiligtum.
>
> Wir betreten feuertrunken, Himmlische, Dein Heiligtum.

Answer (score 5):

`Himmlische` refers to `Freude` which is feminine. It's a nominalization not of the proper adjectiv `himmlisch` but of the adjectiv in its inflected form: `die himmlische Freude`.

The word order in the original sentence is fully normal except for this inclusion, which is a normal addressing inclusion. (I don't know the proper term for it.)

Comment: So Himmlishe in this context means something along the lines of "O, the heavenly one" referring to Joy?

Comment: @ArmenTsirunyan Yes, it means "O, heavenly joy".